# Spring MVC - generic HTTP handlers

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller, servlets, resources

Have searched around and have not found a conclusive answer to this.

I have trying to route all http requests through my dispatcher servlet, and then onto a specific controller.  Ultimately I want to be able to handle resource, AJAX and a.n.other request through the central point.

I currently have the url mapping /* in place to do this. My controllers use @RequestMapping("/[My resource].*") to capture my .htm requests.  Unfortunately Spring appears to use RequestDispactcher.forward to resolve the .jsp from the InternalResourceViewResolver which is then hitting the front controller again and ultimately causing a 404 error.

My question is, am I able to setup a generic catch all that will handle any HTTP request other than the regular view request ?

The HTTP handler must be able to pass requests on to other servers and resolve internal and external resources e.g. images, css etc.

Regards,
Andy

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A think a better idea is to change the servlet-mapping of `DispatcherServlet` to `/` instead of `/*`, this is because `/*` makes all request come to this servlet, instead like you have found for the jsp forwards also, inspite of the fact that there is a JSPServlet mapping for the jsps, the `/` mapping on the other hand will be defaulted to only if a specific mapping is not found for the requested path.

Comment: What if I want all requests to go via the DispatcherServlet ? utimately I want it to flow like this 1. Check if a I have a mapping for resource e.g. controller, if not controller check if it is an Ajax request, if not delgate to default Servlet for static resource.

Comment: the servlet-mapping of `/` will do exactly that - just remember to add a `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to take take care of static resources in the webapp root.

Comment: Not sure if version 3.2 is buggy but if i include th default servlet handler i get 404 errors as it assumes I am using SimpleUrlHandlerMapper and this doesn't find a match.   If I add the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapper in the servlet context I get a 500 error stating "No adapter for handler .." etc. Very frustrating..!

Comment: Are you not using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`?, that should register the correct handlerAdapters and handlerMappings?

Comment: OK am now and all working after adding validator / slf4j dependencies. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the app servlet mapping to / in web.xml. Like shown below.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To resolve other resources add following tag in your dispatcher servlet xml.
Here resources is the folder containing js, css, images. It is stored under Webcontent folder in maven web application structure. Change it according to your project structure.

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Try this.